Get latest message from group or one to one chat sqllite
Thank you for reading this doubt. I'm facing difficulties fetching latest message from each conversation whether that conversation is one to one or group.
I have figured out, how to fetch latest message for one to one chat. But struggling to fetch the latest message for the group.
CREATE TABLE messages ( sender_id TEXT, receiver_id TEXT, group_id TEXT, message TEXT, timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );

Rows to test on query
INSERT INTO messages (sender_id, receiver_id, group_id, message, timestamp) VALUES 
('user1', NULL, 'groupA', 'Hello, how are you?', '2023-11-04 12:00:00'), 
('user2', NULL, 'groupA', 'I am fine, thank you.', '2023-11-04 12:05:00'), 
('user3', 'user4', NULL, 'What is the weather like today?', '2023-11-04 12:10:00'), 
('user4', 'user3', NULL, 'It is sunny and warm.', '2023-11-04 12:15:00'), 
('user1', NULL, 'groupA', 'Can we meet tomorrow?', '2023-11-05 10:00:00'), 
('user2', NULL, 'groupA', 'Sure, what time?', '2023-11-05 10:05:00'), 
('user3', 'user4', NULL, 'Did you finish the report?', '2023-11-05 11:00:00'), 
('user4', 'user3', NULL, 'Almost, I''ll send it by evening.', '2023-11-05 11:05:00'), 
('user5', NULL, 'groupC', 'Let''s go for dinner tonight.', '2023-11-05 18:00:00'), 
('user6',NULL, 'groupC', 'Sounds good, where should we go?', '2023-11-05 18:05:00'), 
('user7', 'user8', NULL, 'I need help with this code.', '2023-11-06 09:00:00'), 
('user8', 'user7', NULL, 'Sure, send it over.', '2023-11-06 09:05:00'), 
('user1', NULL, 'groupD', 'Can you join the meeting tomorrow?', '2023-11-06 14:00:00'), 
('user3', NULL, 'groupD', 'Yes, I can make it.', '2023-11-06 14:05:00');

Query to fetch latest message for one to one chat
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.v1 AS sender_id, t.v2 AS receiver_id, MAX(t.timestamp) AS maxTime
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CASE WHEN sender_id < receiver_id THEN sender_id ELSE receiver_id END AS v1,
               CASE WHEN sender_id < receiver_id THEN receiver_id ELSE sender_id END AS v2,
               timestamp
        FROM messages
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.v1, t.v2
) m2
ON ((m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id AND m1.receiver_id = m2.receiver_id) OR (m1.sender_id = m2.receiver_id AND m1.receiver_id = m2.sender_id)) AND m1.timestamp = m2.maxTime

I have tried grouping up with the group_id. But only able to get the rows which have group_id NULL.
Out put should contain only the latest from each conversation.
('user2', NULL, 'groupA', 'Sure, what time?', '2023-11-05 10:05:00'), 
('user4', 'user3', NULL, 'Almost, I''ll send it by evening.', '2023-11-05 11:05:00'), 
('user6',NULL, 'groupC', 'Sounds good, where should we go?', '2023-11-05 18:05:00'), 
('user8', 'user7', NULL, 'Sure, send it over.', '2023-11-06 09:05:00'), 
('user3', NULL, 'groupD', 'Yes, I can make it.', '2023-11-06 14:05:00')

UPDATE
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.v1 AS sender_id, t.v2 AS receiver_id, MAX(t.timestamp) AS maxTime
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CASE WHEN sender_id < receiver_id THEN sender_id ELSE receiver_id END AS v1,
               CASE WHEN sender_id < receiver_id THEN receiver_id ELSE sender_id END AS v2,
               timestamp
        FROM messages
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.v1, t.v2
) m2
ON ((m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id AND m1.receiver_id = m2.receiver_id) OR (m1.sender_id = m2.receiver_id AND m1.receiver_id = m2.sender_id)) AND m1.timestamp = m2.maxTime 
UNION ALL 
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE group_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY group_id

Able to get latest messages only where reciever is available. But for the group only able to get any random message.

Just select the line within each group whose timestamp is the max one.
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE group_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING timestamp = MAX(timestamp)


This will only return the rows which has group_id available.

I thought that was what you wanted. You can use UNION ALL on the two queries if you want to merge them.

Solved the selection for the group but not getting latest message.

How is the output different from the expected one for the sample data?

This query can be used to solve this issue
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.v1 AS sender_id, t.v2 AS receiver_id, MAX(t.timestamp) AS maxTime
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CASE WHEN sender_id < receiver_id THEN sender_id ELSE receiver_id END AS v1,
               CASE WHEN sender_id < receiver_id THEN receiver_id ELSE sender_id END AS v2,
               timestamp
        FROM messages
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.v1, t.v2
) m2
ON ((m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id AND m1.receiver_id = m2.receiver_id) OR (m1.sender_id = m2.receiver_id AND m1.receiver_id = m2.sender_id)) AND m1.timestamp = m2.maxTime 
UNION ALL 
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(timestamp) AS maxTime
    FROM messages
  GROUP BY group_id
) m3
ON m1.timestamp = m3.maxTime

